# Is there a good way to remotely get javascript debug information from an end-user?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to solve a Javascript problem on my company's site that a single user has reported, but have exhausted all possible fixes I can think of.  To do more, I'll need more information about what's happening in the user's browser.  Can anyone suggest a bookmarklet or other tool I can send to this user to print a log of all Ajax calls and exceptions raised, so the user can send it back to me?

Comment: FYI, I'm looking for a solution that won't require me to modify the code running on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Firebug Lite. An automated system that could send me the information directly would have been better, of course, but there wasn't time to set that up. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Log all the information you want in a cookie and have the customer send the cookie back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few framework for logging to the browser console in JS, log4Javascript is the one I've used and had good luck with.  Alternately, you could send back relevant log information in an AJAX call to a server-side script that writes out a client log and the customer wouldn't have to mess around with sending logs or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

A try-catch block around the "suspect" part of your code.
- and some form of submit in the catch-part, sending details of the incident back to the server - eg. via a form-submit in a hidden iframe or Ajax..